# Exclusion conditions for Multiple criterias

Tags: c#

i have the following line:

```
if (PhoneNumber.EndsWith("_L") || PhoneNumber.EndsWith("_K"))
    Continue;
```

what I want to know how to add another argument to exclude the PhoneNumber.Lenght !=4
meaning if filed with phone number has only 4 digits exclude it as well like the other 2 conditions above

I tried the following:

```
if (PhoneNumber.EndsWith("_L") || PhoneNumber.EndsWith("_K") || PhoneNumber.Lenght !=4)
    Continue;
```

it did not work.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what or how it didn't work?

Comment: the code gets executed fine but it returns no calls which I know it is not true, when debug the code I see that there are 40 calls and 6 are with 4 digits which they should be excluded the I should get only 32 calls since the other 2 ends with _L

Comment: Logically both your and my `if` statements are correct according to your requirements. It sounds to me like the bug lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (PhoneNumber.EndsWith("_L") || PhoneNumber.EndsWith("_K") || PhoneNumber.Lenght ==4)
    Continue;
```

`PhoneNumber.Lenght ==4` not `PhoneNumber.Lenght !=4`

Comment: What is `Lenght` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `Continue)` is, but it's *not* valid C# syntax. If `Continue)` is supposed to represent a `continue` statement then this is what you want:

```
if (phoneNumber.EndsWith("_L") || phoneNumber.EndsWith("_K") || phoneNumber.Length != 4)
{
    continue;
}
```